# Validation for ANOVA question

Tags: anova, statistical-significance

Can someone help me validate my answer to this question:

[image]

My answers come from the first row, where the significances are 0.0002,0.0011, and 0.0005, respectively.  Since they are all below 5%, then the conclusion should be correct, right?  Am I thinking about this incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see at the top of the table, you are doing the comparison between the means of I-J, so the Null hypothesis is: Is the mean of J different from the mean of I? In the very first row you have the difference between 1 and 2, which has a Sig. of 0.0002. You can say that the mean of type 1 is different  from the mean of type 2. In the second row you have the difference between 1 and 3, and so on. So, the rigth answer is (i), (ii) and (iii)